# Fatal Error with WP Forms

Tags: forms

I am trying to install my recently purchased WPForms Pro and when I try to Activate it, it gives me a fatal error. I am using a Managed Wordpress site from GoDaddy, so I don't have access to the wp-admin. It had been working for months before, so I don't know how to fix.

```
Warning: require(/home/content/a2pewpnaspod05_data04/37/41535537/html/wp-content/install.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/content/a2pewpnaspod05_data04/37/41535537/html/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 13

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/content/a2pewpnaspod05_data04/37/41535537/html/wp-content/install.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_6/lib/php') in /home/content/a2pewpnaspod05_data04/37/41535537/html/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 13
```

Please help!

Comment: try-  open file manager. rename wp-content/plugin folder to plugin-old and create a  new folder "plugins"- if it solves the problem delete the WPForms Pro plugin folder and rename back plugins-old folder to plugins

Comment: It’s a question for WP Forms Pro support.